# How to avoid visual display of intermediate lines when I go to a specific line number in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ctrl

When I use `Ctrl + G` to go to a specific line, the window view jumps directly to that line when a number is entered. However, I don't want to see these 'intermediate lines'.

For example, if I want to go to line `123`, I first see line `1`, then line `12`, and finally line `123`.

So, how can I go directly to line `123` without seeing lines `1` and `12`?